# In which folder does Code store the unsaved text files?

Tags: code

In which folder does Code store the unsaved text files?
I have not clicked the save button and the file name is New Document.
Where is it stored?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Documents that have **never** been saved are stored in:

```
~/.local/share/io.elementary.code/unsaved/
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know in the same directory you made text in as a hidden file.

Comment: This is true for documents that have already been saved somewhere that you're now editing. The question is referring to documents that have never been saved.